# Given a strongly convex smooth function, does there exist a diffeomorphic transformation to a quadratic function?

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, diffeomorphism

I am wondering whether the following property, which seems intuitive in $\mathbb R$, holds in $n$-dimensional Euclidean space.

**Question**: Let a smooth, strongly convex function $V: \mathbb R^d \to \mathbb R$ (strongly convex meaning $\exists \alpha >0, \forall x \in \mathbb R^d: \nabla^2 V(x) \geq \alpha \operatorname{Id}$ as bilinear forms). Does there exists a diffeomorphism $\gamma : \mathbb R^d \to \mathbb R^d$ and a positive definite matrix $A$ such that the following property holds?
\begin{equation*}
\forall x \in \mathbb R^d: \gamma^{-1}\circ V\circ  \gamma(x) = x^T A x
\end{equation*}

Any references or help is appreciated.

**Note**: I am not interested in an expression for $\gamma$, just whether it exists.

**Motivation**: My motivation comes from convex optimisation, where it is easier to prove properties for quadratic optimisation problems than for arbitrary convex optimisation problems. Hence, I am wondering whether one can equate to any strongly convex function a strongly convex quadratic function up to a diffeomorphism.

Comment: Amir Ali Ahmadi, Alex Olshevsky, Pablo A. Parrilo, John N. Tsitsiklis, [NP-hardness of Deciding Convexity of Quartic Polynomials and Related Problems](https://arxiv.org/abs/1012.1908), December 2010 — *"We show that unless P=NP, there exists no polynomial time (or even pseudo-polynomial time) algorithm that can decide whether a multivariate polynomial of degree four (or higher even degree) is globally convex."*

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo yes, strong convexity.

Comment: If it's hard for multivariate polynomials, I assume it's even harder for general smooth functions.

Comment: Thank you for this. However, I am not interested in an expression for the diffeomorphism, just whether it exists. I have edited the post to emphasize this.